How to make basset in Backpack 6 work for project with multi-tenancy structure?
In my multi-tenancy project, I have upgrade the backpack to v6 recently, but have no idea how to config APP_URL in env file. Since each tenant has a different URL, so packages cannot be loaded using basset.
Is it possible to disable the basset feature in new version?

Hi, I think you need dynamic config by creating middleware... something like this $yourTenantDomain = $request->getHost(); config(['app.url' => 'https://' . $yourTenantDomain]);
